# ModalPopupExtender open onclick of GridView row problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, modalpopupextender

(I'm using Lukinha RS's solution to the row onclick functionality)

When I click on a row within the gridview I get a postback before the ModalPopupExtender opens, I dont want the postback however as you see the method I use is the cause. Unfortunatly it is the only way I have been able to get an onClick applied to a gridview row to open the MPE.

Another problem I have is with the MPE open - I click a 'close' button on the popup panal it simply reloads the page resulting with the same popup panal opening.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = e.Row;
    if (row.DataItem == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        switch (e.Row.RowType)
        {
            case DataControlRowType.Header:
                break;

            case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor='hand'");
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));
                break;
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        return;
    }
```

And here is my SelectedIndexChanged

```
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = ((GridView)sender).SelectedRow;
    ModalPopupExtender mpe = (ModalPopupExtender)row.FindControl("ModalPopupExtender1");
    mpe.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunatly it is the only way I have been able to get an onClick
>   applied to a gridview row to open the MPE

Incorrectly. Actually, you CAN open modal extender without postback. 
Change `onclick` attribute value as below:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("javascript:$find('{0}').show();", ModalPopupExtender1.ClientID));
```

Comment: `e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("javascript:$find('{0}').show();", ModalPopupExtender1.ClientID));` is returning null - any suggestions?

Comment: you need to get extender object before as you doing this in `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler and use it `ClientID` property value